# Cloud Watch Event not Triggering when created through Java programatically

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created a Cloud Watch Event using java aws sdk. The cloud watch event got created with the cron expression but unfortunately it seems not firing according to the cron expression

```
PutRuleRequest request = new PutRuleRequest()
                .withName("test1")
                .withDescription("desc1")
                .withScheduleExpression("cron(0/1 * * * ? *)")
                .withState(RuleState.ENABLED);
            PutRuleResult result = cloudWatchEvent.putRule(request);
```

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Have you looked at the event log?

Comment: @Robo I have checked but nothing is coming